# An isomorphism theorem for sheaves.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

Let $\varphi: \cal{F} \longrightarrow \cal{G}$ a morphism of sheaves. My goal is to prove that $im\varphi \simeq \cal{F} / Ker \varphi$.

My thoughts about this problem:

1) $im \varphi(U) \simeq \cal{F}(U) / Ker \varphi(U)$ (a classic result for abelian groups).

2) We have an isomorphism between sheaves iff we have an isomorphism between their stalks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your thought number 1) implies that the presheaf $\mathcal{F}/\ker\varphi$ is isomorphic to the presheaf image of $\varphi$. Hence, the sheafifications of both presheaves are isomorphic, and we're done.

Comment: I'm not sure about how exactly thought 1) implies the isomorphy between the presheaves. I need that the homomorphism (which are isomorphisms) between  the presheaves $im \varphi (U)$ and $\cal{F}/ ker \varphi (U)$ conmute with the restrictions from $im \varphi (V) \longrightarrow im \varphi (U)$ and $\cal{F}/ ker \varphi (V) \longrightarrow \cal{F}/ ker \varphi (U)$ for each $V \subset U$.

Comment: @user210089 I guess they commute since $\varphi$ is a morphism of sheaves. It means that the homomorphisms $\varphi(U):\mathcal{F}(U)\to\mathcal{G}(U)$ commute with the restrictions, and hence so do the homomorphisms you are referring to.

Comment: @Amitai Yuval Can you explain why $U\rightarrow $ $F (U)/Ker\phi _U$ is a sheaf? In general the quotient is not a sheaf.

Comment: @rafa You are right, it is not a sheaf in general. However, it is a *presheaf*.